# composer, laravel and 2 versions of PHP

Tags: php, laravel, centos, composer-php

I am having trouble getting composer and laravel to work nicely on my server,

if I run,

`php composer.phar update`

I get the following error,

> Problem 1
>       - laravel/framework v4.2.9 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
>       - laravel/framework v4.2.8 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
>       - laravel/framework v4.2.7 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
>       - laravel/framework v4.2.6 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
>       - laravel/framework v4.2.5 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
>       - laravel/framework v4.2.4 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
>       - laravel/framework v4.2.3 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
>       - laravel/framework v4.2.2 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
>       - laravel/framework v4.2.11 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
>       - laravel/framework v4.2.10 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
>       - laravel/framework v4.2.1 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
>       - laravel/framework v4.2.0 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
>       - laravel/framework v4.2.11 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
>       - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.2.* -> satisfiable by   laravel/framework[v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.2, v4.2.3,
>   v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].

Now I think this because `php` on my $PATH is pointing to /usr/local/bin and that version of PHP is 5.3, however I also have PHP 5.5.14 installed on my server, and I can point composer straight to that version like this,

```
/usr/local/php-5.5.14-cgi/bin/php composer.phar update
```

Then I get the following error,

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/popsapp.com/api.popsapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php
>   on line 411 Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the
>   post-update-cmd event returned with an error The disk hosting
>   /var/www/vhosts/popsapp.com/.composer is full, this may be the cause
>   of the following exception
>
> ```
>                                                                                                 [RuntimeException]
> ```
>
> Error Output: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/popsapp.com/a
>   pi.popsapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php
>   on line 411
>
> update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev]
>   [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers]
>   [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies]
>   [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
>   [--ignore-platform-reqs] [packages1] ... [packagesN]

Which leads my to believe that either composer or larvel is still using the wrong version of php, how can I make sure that the full installation uses PHP 5.5.14?

Answer (score 2):

During `composer update`, composer is calling the scripts in the `composer.json` file. For Laravel this file looks something like:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
```

So you can either update your `composer.json` to use the right version of PHP or just update your $PATH variable. I would suggest the later.

Answer (score 0):

LARAVEL installation on Linux OS ubntu 14.04:

## STEP 1 : Install latest PHP version

You can remove earlier php version by following command:

```
sudo apt-get purge php
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php7.1
```

## STEP 2 : Install Composer

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
composer
```

## STEP 3 : INSTALL LARAVEL 5.4

1] Go to your working project directory and run following commands:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravel_5.4
cd laravel_5.4
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Gaurav/laravel_5.4
composer install
```

2] If you get fatal error while installing composer regrading mbstring use following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.1-mbstring php-gettext libapache2-mod-php7.1
composer update
```

3] To run laravel project

```
php artisan serve
php artisan key:generate
```

Go to http://127.0.0.1:8000 in your browser and you will see the home screen of laravel